# Pester: not all mocked functions are intercepted

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

I have a number of modules, including **ModuleMain** and **ModuleSql**. There is an interdependence between the modules such that **Main-Function** in ModuleMain uses 4 functions from ModuleSql:

```
function Main-Function {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]

  # The following 4 lines are all wrapped in $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess() and
  # try {} catch {} logic. I have left that out in this post, but I mention
  # it in case it is relevant.

  $a = New-SqlConnection
  $b = Invoke-SqlStoredProc -connection $a
  $c = Invoke-SqlQuery -connection $a
  Close-SqlConnection -connection $a | Out-Null
  return $c
}
```

I have created a **Function-Main1.tests.ps1** file to test Function-Main1. At first I used `InModuleScope` but then switched to specifying the module per-mock with the `-ModuleName` parameter.

```
Import-Module "ModuleMain" -Force

Describe "Main-Function" {

  Mock -ModuleName ModuleMain New-SqlConnection {
    return $true }
  Mock -ModuleName ModuleMain Invoke-SqlStoredProc {
    return $true }
  Mock -ModuleName ModuleMain Invoke-SqlQuery {
    return $true }
  Mock -ModuleName ModuleMain Close-SqlConnection {
    return $true }

  Context "When calling Main-Function with mocked SQL functions" {
    It "Calls each SQL function once" {
      Assert-MockCalled -Scope Context -ModuleName ModuleMain -CommandName New-SqlConnecion -Times 1 -Exactly
      Assert-MockCalled -Scope Context -ModuleName ModuleMain -CommandName Invoke-SqlStoredProc -Times 1 -Exactly
      Assert-MockCalled -Scope Context -ModuleName ModuleMain -CommandName Invoke-SqlQuery -Times 1 -Exactly
      Assert-MockCalled -Scope Context -ModuleName ModuleMain -CommandName Close-SqlConnecion -Times 1 -Exactly
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this test I get the following results:

```
[-] Calls each SQL function once 223ms
  Expected Invoke-SqlStoredProc in module ModuleMain to be called 1 times exactly but was called 0 times
  at line: xx in 
  xx:       Assert-MockCalled -Scope Context -ModuleName ModuleMain -CommandName Invoke-SqlStoredProc -Times 1 -Exactly
```

Note the following:

1. I did not import ModuleSql, where the *-Sql* functions are defined, since I am mocking them all anyway.
2. I have observerd/worked out that I need to set `-ModuleName` to be the module where **Main-Function** is defined and not the one where the SQL function (that I am trying to mock) is defined.
3. I have played around with `InModuleScope` and `-ModuleName`, e.g. setting one or other to be **ModuleSQL**, but mainly that just made things worse.

By playing around, adding Verbose output in the other mocked functions, I have confirmed that `New-SqlConnection` and `Close-SqlConnection` are both being intercepted, but `Invoke-SqlStoredProc` and `Invoke-SqlQuery` are not.

Probing deeper, I can see that the following exception is being thrown by the `Invoke-Sql*` (mocked) functions: **Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'."** This *is* behaviour that I would expect when the real versions of those functions are called, but I am expecting that the mocked versions would ignore parameter types.

**Why would Pester intercept only 2 of my 4 functions?**

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]? Currently I do not even see where did you call `Main-Function` as part of test.

Comment: Not sure how easy it will be to create a MCV version of what I'm doing without needing to add in all the Sql function definitions, etc. I have just added a little more debug that I pulled out of the testing.

Comment: I run the test by loading the .tests.ps1 file in PowerShell ISE and pressing F5!

Comment: Mocked functions does not ignore parameter types.

Comment: Just to clarify further, my evidence that the functions are not being intercepted is (1) the error message generated by `Assert-MockCalled` and (2) the exception caught which suggests that the real function is being called with invalid inputs.

Comment: Ah, they don't ignore parameter types... That would probably explain it. The two functions that are not being intercepted require the `-connection` to be a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` type. I guess I'll have to update the `New-SqlConnection` mock to return such an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the short answer to this question was given in the comments above:

> Mocked functions does not ignore parameter types.  --PetSerAl

This meant that when I was trying to call the `Invoke-Sql*` functions, and using the phony **$sqlConnection** variable (simply set to **$true**) this was causing an error since the input parameter wasn't the expected data type.

And the solution in my case was to mock the `New-SqlConnection` function so it returned a `[System.Data.SqlCient.SqlConnection]` object. As it happens, I also reverted back to using `InModuleScope` rather than specifying the module on each Mock:

```
InModuleScope "ModuleMain" {
  Describe "MainFunction" {

    Mock New-SqlConnection {
      New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlCient.SqlConnection
    }

    ...
}
```